# How to resize byobu in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, resize, byobu

I was a happy user of `byobu` for many months. I was running it between two Ubuntu 11.10 machines and I never had a problem with window sizes. From my laptop I would connect through `ssh` to my workstation, run `byobu` and then I could resize the terminal and `byobu` would always fill all the possible space.

Since I upgraded to 12.10 this does not work properly anymore. In the laptop I can resize it up to a maximum size (which I assume is connected to the size of the original terminal where I run `byobu` in the workstation), but if I try to make it bigger I get something like: http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=222048&d=1343755591

I have tried <kbd>F12</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> :fit in order to try and resize the window, but I get no changes .

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Thanks,
Ángel de Vicente

Comment: I think this problem only happens with the default backend (tmux). I have no changed to the screen backend and I can resize to whatever size I want without any problems.